# Which projection conserves lengths?

Tags: coordinate-system, terminology

I would like to crop rectangular fragments of given size and for these purposes I need coordinates, which covers all Earth and measured in meters.

I wrote the following picture:

[image]

Latitude and longiture are in radians.

I mapped all surface into leaf-like 2D shape.

`x` coordinate is a distance in meters from zero meridian along parallel.

`y` coordiante is a distance in meters from equator along meridian.

What is the name of this projection?

Comment: Note that this projection won't conserve arbitrary distances, so your question title might be somewhat misleading.

Comment: How much of the globe are you working with?

Comment: @das-g probably you are right...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sinusoidal projection should come closest to what you mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_projection